# C++ Printf Style Formatting for Std::String

Tags: c++, string, std

I was writing a utility function to do sprintf like formatting for std::string or std::wstring based on Unicode settings.

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
typedef std::wstring MyString ;
typedef TCHAR MyChar ;
#define MYTEXT TEXT
#else
typedef std::string MyString ;
typedef char MyChar ;
#define MYTEXT
#endif //_UNICODE

MyString Utils::GetStringPrintf(const MyString kstrText, ...)
{
    int iCharsWritten = 0 ;
    MyString strFinal ;
    MyChar szBufferTouse[8194] ; //Hopefully Long enough
    va_list     fmtList ;
    va_start(fmtList, kstrText) ;
    /*int iVal = va_arg(fmtList, int) ;*/ =>Just for debugging

#ifdef _UNICODE
    iCharsWritten = _stprintf_s(szBufferTouse,  8194, kstrText.c_str(), fmtList) ;
#else
    iCharsWritten = sprintf_s(szBufferTouse, 8194, kstrText.c_str(), fmtList) ;
#endif //_UNICODE

    va_end(fmtList) ;
    strFinal = szBufferTouse ;
    return strFinal ;
}
```

When called like :

```
int iId = 2 ;
MyString strFileName = Utils::GetStringPrintf(MYTEXT("Student_%d.png"), iId) ;
```

//For Unicode am getting
Student_1633600.png instead of  Student_2.png
//For non-Unicode am getting
Student_1633800.png instead of  Student_2.png

Upon debugging I do get the value of iVal as 2, but somehow the values get bad upon passing to sprintf.

However if I call, sprintf directly,

```
MyChar szFilename[200] ;
int iId = 2 ;
_stprintf_s(szFilename, 200, MYTEXT("Student_%d.png"), iId) ;
```

Am getting proper output, i.e
Student_2.png

I did refer other posts in Stack Overflow regarding sprintf functionality and found my code to be doing quite similar to those.
Is there any problem in passing va_list repeatedly to functions.

Comment: Totally unrelated but very life-saving tip: drop the silly `TCHAR` and `_UNICODE` business ASAP. Do you really want to support Win98? Because that is essentially the only reason for its use. Either use `wchar_t` and be able to call the "wide" Win32 API functions directly, or use `char` and UTF-8, and convert when you need to. If you really need full-blown no-exceptions Unicode, use something like ICU and don't do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `sprintf_s` with `vsprintf`(and remove size) or with `vsprintf_s` if available.

Quoting from manpage of printf. (Emphasis mine)

> The functions **vprintf(), vfprintf(), vsprintf(), vsnprintf()** are
>   equivalent to the functions **printf(), fprintf(), sprintf(),
>   snprintf()**, respectively, except that they are called with a **va_list**
>   instead of a **variable number of arguments**. These functions do not call
>   the va_end macro. Because they invoke the va_arg macro, the value of
>   ap is undefined after the call.

Comment: @alk Thanks for extending the answer and make it more useful. I believed it exists if sprintf_s does. Because it is the building block for sprintf. But I am not sure about the MS environment and their safe function implementation so warned OP to check availability. vprintf on the other hand is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: @MohitJain Thanks for the answer and indeed it worked like a charm.
For Windows environment, StringCchVPrintf can also be used.